# Transformation matrices only for one shape

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

Good evening.

I'm trying to rotate a line on a canvas using setRotation -method and it works perfectly, unless you want to draw another shape on the same canvas. After using Canvas's concat -method, the entire canvas will be rotated, let's say, by 30 degrees counterclockwise/clockwise. And this is the problem. I would like to rotate only the line and I don't want to rotate any other shapes on this canvas or the entire canvas. I found out that the bitmap could be drawn with matrices, but it looks cumbersome and clumsy. Also, there was a suggestion to setup a new matrix for the Canvas, in fact, this proposition works neither.

So, the question sounds simple enough, how could the only one shape on the canvas be rotated without using OpenGl and affecting on other shapes on the canvas?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Here is the code with comments and other stuff:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    int startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    startY = stopY = 100;
    startX = 100;
    stopX = 200;
    this.paint = new Paint();
    //this.path = new Path();
    this.matrix = canvas.getMatrix();
    this.paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    this.paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    this.matrix.setRotate(180, startX, startY);
    canvas.concat(this.matrix);
    /*this.matrix.setTranslate(startX, 0);
    canvas.concat(this.matrix);*/

    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, this.paint);

    canvas.setMatrix(new Matrix());
    //canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 50, paint);
}
```

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient way to go about rotating a line. It would be rather simple to calculate its new x and y endpts after rotation.

Comment: @Mozoby, what would you suggest instead of using rotation?

p.s. Don't give too much credits to the code above. It was only example.

Comment: There is another way to rotate only one shape. But it seems a bit clumsy: canvas.rotate(90, startX, startY);
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, this.paint);
  

  canvas.rotate(-90, startX, startY);

Comment: I suggest transforming and translating the actual line coordinates rather than the whole canvas. This can be done with linear algebra. This should help: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-8P4ZK5/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-8P4ZK5

Comment: @Mozoby, I thought of that, to be honest. I assumed, if framework has this functions already, why should I implement them on my own. But, you are right in this case, it will reduce the overhead of translation and transformation, if I'll do only for one line, not for the entire canvas.

Comment: BTW, Texas Instruments provides a better tool for such tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `Canvas.save()` and `Canvas.restore()` for this. They supposedly put current matrix into stack and you can return back to previous one once done with the modified matrix.

```
this.matrix.setRotate(180, startX, startY);
canvas.save();
canvas.concat(this.matrix);
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, this.paint);
canvas.restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

Mozoboy proposed the idea of using the linear algebra. Here is a new code of the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method with using linear algebra and staying in the scopes of the Android APIs:

```
    Matrix m = new Matrix();       //Declaring a new matrix
    float[] vecs = {7, 3};    //Declaring an end-point of the line

   /*Declaring the initial values of the matrix 
     according to the theory of the 3 
     dimensional chicken in 2D space 
    There is also 4D chicken in 3D space*/

    float[] initial = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};    
    m.setValues(initial);   
    float[] tmp = new float[9];    //Debug array of floats
    m.setRotate(90, 4.0f, 3.0f);    //Rotating by 90 degrees around the (4, 3) point
/*Mapping our vector to the matrix. 
  Similar to the multiplication of two
  matrices 3x3 by 1x3. 
  In our case they are (matrix m after rotating) multiplied by      
  (7)
  (3)
  (1) according to the theory*/ 

  m.mapPoints(vecs);             

    for(float n : vecs)
    {
        Log.d("VECS", "" + n);     //Some debug info
    }

    m.getValues(tmp);
    for(float n : tmp)
    {
        Log.d("TMP", "" + n);      //also debug info
    }
```

As a result of this algorithm, we have a new coordinates of the line's end point (4, 6).